# how can i reduce the number of whitespaces in a sentence to 1 if there are more then 1 whitespaces in the sentence?

Tags: java

How can i reduce the number of whitespaces in a sentence to 1 if there are more then 1 whitespaces in the sentence?

Comment: Do you mean consecutive whitespace?  Edit your post to show a sample input and what you want for output.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean "consecutive" whitespaces, here's a solution.

```
String sentence = "hello   here are \n some   whitespaces.";
String newString = sentence.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
System.out.println(newString);
```

**Output:**

```
hello here are some whitespaces.
```

Comment: A string of words with whitespaces in between.